# Concatanate tuples in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples that looks something like this:

```
tuples = [('a', 10, 11), ('b', 13, 14), ('a', 1, 2)]
```

Is there a way that i can join them together based on the first index of every tuple to make a each tuple contain 5 elements. I know for a fact there isn't more that 2 of each letter in the tuples, Ie more than 2 'a's or 'b's in the entire list. The other requirement is to use Python2.6. I cant figure out the logic to it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Desired Output:

```
tuples = [('a', 10, 11, 1, 2), ('b', 13, 14, 0, 0)]
```

I have tried creating a new list of first elements and adding the other elements to it but then I only have a list and not list of tuples.

EDIT to provide previous tried code,

Created a new list: `templist, resultList = [], []`

Populate templist with the first element in every tuple:

```
for i in tuples:
    templist.append(i[0])

elemlist = list(set(templist))

for i in elemlist:
    for j in tuples:
        if i == j[0]:
            resultlist.append((i, j[1], j[2]))
```

This just returns the same list of tuples, How can i hold onto it and append every `j[1] j[2]` that corresponds to correct `j[0]`

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are only one or two of every letter in the list as stated:

```
import itertools

tuples = [('a', 10, 11), ('b', 13, 14), ('a', 1, 2)]

result = []
key = lambda t: t[0]
for letter,items in itertools.groupby(sorted(tuples,key=key),key):
    items = list(items)
    if len(items) == 1:
        result.append(items[0]+(0,0))
    else:
        result.append(items[0]+items[1][1:])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('a', 10, 11, 1, 2), ('b', 13, 14, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you I have been stuck on the logic of this for ages, Much appreciated.